# Mark revision as non-eligible to be merged

Tags: svn, merge

I'm currently doing a pretty heavy task: merging a bunch of revision from the project trunk to some branches, full of conflicts.

I would like to take this process to perform some cleanup once some revisions, will never be merged from the trunk to the branches.

It is possible to mark some specific revision(s) as non-eligible to merged?

Answer (score 5):

You can merge the revision to said location but use the --record-only flag.  So if r3 of branches/b1 should never be merged to trunk, you could do this:

svn merge -c3 --record-only ^/branches/b1 .

Where your current working directory is the working copy pointing to trunk.  Commit that change, which should only be svn:mergeinfo changes, and you should disallow merging that revision from /branches/b1 to /trunk.

Comment: Hi! I'll try to apply your solution. I would also like to know, if its possible to mark a revision as non-eligible on the commit itself?

Comment: You lost me.  "non-eligible on the commit itself"?

Comment: No, you can't mark it non-eligible when it's first committed.  We sometimes put the phrase "don't merge" in the log message, as an aid to the person who will later do the merge, but there's nothing you can do that SVN itself will recognize.

Comment: If I understand, Matt is correct.  You can't make a commit and make it unmergeable without using some thirdparty tool/process.  The example I gave you will do what you seek.  I know it's not the way you want but Subversion doesn't allow what you want out of the box.

Comment: Ok, I'll try your example and give some feedback asap.

Answer (score 1):

As @jeremy-whitlock answered, committing the merge as "record-only" is they way to go.

For those of you using TortoiseSVN, this option will be on the second Merge dialog:
[image: screenshot of TortoiseSVN's Merge dialog]